# Is there a shortcut for assigning some variable with the return value of a method that's used on it in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I often do the following:

```
@value = @value.some_method
```

But isn't there a shorter syntax for that in ruby? Some methods offer bang equivalents, but sadly not all...

For iterations one can use:

```
 i += 1
```

Is that, or something similar, also available for my code snippet above?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information. If `some_method` has a `some_method!` version that can mutate your `@value`, then, yes, you can do that. If `some_method` is something you wrote, then write a version. Without a lot more detail we can't give anything else but a very generic answer.

Comment: a generic answer is what i want ;) some_method is a placeholder for every method, and not all methods do have a bang version. I'd need a solution that would work in all cases, but I'm afraid there is nothing shorter in ruby -.-

Comment: There is no common, universal, way to make all methods do that. You'd find that attempts to change `self` would raise exceptions left and right. We, as the programmer, selectively mutate objects where it's safe to do, not blindly expecting some magic to step in and protect us when we do something "really bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that does this in a shorter way.

To be fair, it is an unusual pattern, and while not especially rare, would lead to confusion if there was an operator like:

```
@value .= some_method
```

How is that even supposed to be parsed when reading?

As [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) points out, in-place operators are really what are best here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that taking the actual variable as the receiver because there is no way to get to the name of the variable. Instead, you need to use the name of the variable like this:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :value
  def change_to_do_something name
    instance_variable_set(name, "do something")
  end
end

a = A.new

a.value = "Hello"
p a.value
# => "Hello"

a.change_to_do_something(:@value)
p a.value
# => "do something"
```